# Getting UDP packet Details in NEPacketTunnelProvider

Tags: ios, swift, vpn

I want to get the details like IP address of source & destination along with the port numbers from the UDP packet we received in

```
 self.packetFlow.readPackets { [weak self] (packets: [Data], protocols: [NSNumber]) in
        }
```

I am using following code to for creating session so assuming that the packet will be UDP

```
self.session = self.createUDPSession(to: NWHostEndpoint(hostname: serverAddress, port: serverPort), from: nil)
```

where self.sssion is `var session: NWUDPSession?`

Do someone has any pointers how to do this in swift ?

I am looking for some code as I am relatively  new to packet level things.

Comment: Can you add some more code please? 
Like, which API are you using for UDP?

Comment: Hi @YanivH I am not sure what kind of packet this is .But what i need is details of the packet. Like source, destination address etc.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand correctly, but why don't you read that from the NWUDPSession.resolvedEndpoint?    
Or, If you are controlling the endpoint on the other side, you can add this to the data that is been sent on the packet itself.  


In addition, If you don't mind using Obj-C, I found this to be really helpful and straight forward with UDP:
[https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket]

Hope this will help in any way

Comment: @YanivH can you help me with some code how to handle iPPackets.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to read the source and destination address, along with ports of the packet using IPPacket class in [NEKIT](https://github.com/zhuhaow/NEKit) iOS Code. Hope this will help someone who face this kind of scenerio.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a solution such as [BinUtils](https://github.com/nst/BinUtils) to unpack the array of Data packets received from the packetFlow.readPackets() method. These are IP packets received from your applications. You will need to define the the format for an the IP Header and UDP Header yourself.